# Java Script and RegEx

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, regex

In application that I'am working on I have dynamically generated UI it is number of controls and listed entries depends on records from DB.
What I'am trying to achieve is to write RegEx that would help me extract some numbers assigned as part of controls ID.

The way how I'am assigning IDs is : cText+(row that it represents in its group)+G+(group number).
For example cText4G12

What I'am looking for is to get from that ID what Row it represents in example is 4 and it's group 12. 
 I've never used RegEx before so I'am asking for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx is not something that is easy to get your head around, so I would strongly recommend that you spend a bit of time to learn it - as it will be beneficial to you in the long run.

However, against my best judgement - here is code that will get you what you need..

```
var id = "cText4G12";
var result = id.match(/^cText(\d+)G(\d+)$/);

result[1] will contain "4"
result[2] will contain "12"
```

Comment: Thank you for help it **works** perfectly ! It's about time to learn RegEx :) Have nice day

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `regex`. You can simply do:

```
var my_id = "cText4G12";
var row = my_id.slice(my_id.indexOf("cText")+5,my_id.indexOf("G"));
var group = my_id.slice(my_id.indexOf("G")+1);
```